# Create std::tuple of types "contained" in another std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, tuples, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I have a `std::tuple` created from a variadic template function

```
std::tuple<Args&...> mytup(args...);
```

Each object in `args` has defined a type `value_type`.

Now, I want to create a `std::tuple` called `mynewtup` of the same length of `mytup` but of types the different types `value_type`. Moreover, each `args` has a method `f()` which return a `value_type` and `mynewtup` need to be created calling that function.

In other words, I would like to do something like (pseudocode)

```
std::tuple<typename args1::value_type,....> mynewtup(args1.f(),....);
```

Is it possible to do that? How?

Comment: `std::make_tuple(args.f()...)` ?

Comment: Oh well. Let me make this an answer then.

Comment: Wouldn't just removing the `,`s in the above "this is what I want to do" work?

Comment: Yes, you are right. With your answer I have just noticed how stupid was my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `std::make_tuple` as follows :

```
auto mynewtup = std::make_tuple(args.f()...);
```